# How to parcelable an object with an array of another object

Tags: android, arrays, object, parcelable

I'm trying to do a Parcelable Object to pass data between activities. With the primary variables I don't have issues, but now I need to pass an array of another object, and I don't know how to do it. I'm searching for some examples, but I didn't find a similar case to my problem.

This is my source code of the principal object:

```
public class Quiz implements Parcelable {

    int event_id;
    String name;
    String business_unit;
    int functional_area_business;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
    int functional_area_support;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
    Answer [] list_answers;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
    ...
    //


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Quiz> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Quiz>() {
        public Quiz createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Quiz(in);
        }

        public Quiz[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Quiz[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(event_id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(business_unit);
        dest.writeInt(functional_area_business);
        dest.writeInt(functional_area_support);
        dest.writeArray(list_answers);
    }

    private Quiz(Parcel in) {
        event_id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        business_unit = in.readString();
        functional_area_business = in.readInt();
        functional_area_support = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

The other class is the next.

```
public class Answer {

    int answer_id;
    String value;

}
```

If someone could tell me what I need to modify, I will be gratefully.

Comment: Have you ever thought about also implementing `Parcelable` for `Answer`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to read or write data in the array

Comment: I don't understand what you mean just implement `Parcelable` for `Answer` and then write the `Answer[]` to the parcel with `writeParcelableArray()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ArrayList instead of an Array and make Answer class Parceable then update your code to the following:

```
  public class Quiz implements Parcelable {

        int event_id;
        String name;
        String business_unit;
        int functional_area_business;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
        int functional_area_support;    // 0 unchecked, 1 checked
        List<Answer >  list_answers;

        //GETTERS AND SETTERS
        ...
        //


        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Quiz> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Quiz>() {
            public Quiz createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Quiz(in);
            }

            public Quiz[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Quiz[size];
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

    @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(event_id);
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(business_unit);
            dest.writeInt(functional_area_business);
            dest.writeInt(functional_area_support);
            dest.writeTypedList(list_answers);
        }

    private Quiz(Parcel in) {
            event_id = in.readInt();
            name = in.readString();
            business_unit = in.readString();
            functional_area_business = in.readInt();
            functional_area_support = in.readInt();
            list_answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
            in.readTypedList(list_answers , Answer.CREATOR);
        }
    }
```

And this is the Parceable Answer:

```
    public class Answer implements Parcelable  {

        int answer_id;
        String value;



public static final Parcelable.Creator<Answer> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Answer>() {
            public Answer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Answer(in);
            }

            public Answer[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Answer[size];
            }
        };
       @Override
            public int describeContents() {
                return 0;
            }

        @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                dest.writeInt(answer_id);
                dest.writeString(value);

    }
    private Answer(Parcel in) {
                answer_id = in.readInt();
                value = in.readString();
    }

    }
```

Comment: dest.writeTypedList(list_answers); sais that Answer class need to implement Parcelable. Do I need to do it too? I think so. Another error is that in the line in.readTypedList(list_answers , Answer.CREATOR); sais that it cannot resolve the symbol "CREATOR". Thanks

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I'm absorbing new concepts. Thanks

Comment: Another question please, to call this in an intent to pass data is like any other tutorial or it has a special treat? Thanks

Comment: Mohamed, when I try to create a class to fill data before send it in an intent with Quiz quiz = new Quiz(); IDE sais me that "Quiz(Parcel) in Quiz cannot be applied to ()". Why?

Comment: add this constructor public Quiz () {}

Comment: Thank you, I did it yesterday.

Comment: Mohamed, I need to send between activities a list of quizs. Do I need to make parcelable a need class with only a List<Quiz> variable? Could you explain me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Intent in = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
in.putParcelableArrayListExtra("MyParacableList", new ArrayList<Quiz>());
startActivity(intent);